# Can some share how to write vim map

Tags: vim

new to vim, recently came across mapping keyboards issues, what get on google and stackoverflow is only something like this `map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>` and `map <A-]> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>`, then I searched Vim documentation: map http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#<>, but what it also does not explains the syntax, the meanning of the symbols, can someone suggest some reference materials for this? Thanks very much!

Comment: not the right place for this question, you are probably confused because of the keys in there, have a look here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)

Comment: Also, vim's built in documentation is excellent: Try ``:help :map``, ``:help map.txt``, ``:help 05.3``

Comment: @codeape Great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mapping like the ones you mentioned has three parts:

- the type of mapping (`map`/`nmap`/`imap`/`vmap`/... and the corresponding `noremap` versions). This determines in what modes the mapping is active. `map` means normal mode, visual mode and operator-pending mode. When using `noremap`/`nnoremap`/... the mapping is made with respect to Vims standard keybindings, otherwise the mappings can themselves call mappings.
- The key(s) to bind. This can be a normal key, a control character like `<C-\>`, or a sequence of keys.
- a key sequence to map to.

In your first case, you map the key `<C-\>` (control-backspace) to `:tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>` in normal, visual, and operator-pending mode.

Comment: I tried to create one map as: `:map <LeftMouse> :exec "tag ". expand("<cword>")<CR>`, to jump to the definition of cursor with left click of mouse, but it does not work, since it is only small modification of the previous command, I'm confused why it does not work, the previous one work properly, could you help? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to look up the definition of a word by clicking on it? In that case you don't want to completely override the `<LeftMouse>` functionality, but instead call that and _then_ do what you want: `:noremap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>:exec "tag ". expand("<cword>")<CR>`

Comment: `:set tags=./tags;/
:noremap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>:exec "tag ". expand("<cword>")<CR>
:map <C-j> :tab split<CR>:exec "tjump ".expand("<cword>")<CR>
`, thank you, now the `~/.vimrc` is like this, `ctrl+j` works properly, but the second one still not work

Comment: `:noremap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>:exec "tag ". expand("<cword>")<CR>` this one doesn't work, clicking leftmouse no response, `ctrl+j` and `ctrl+]` works

Comment: I don't have tags, so I can't properly test it, but the mapping works (when I click on a word I get "tag not found: thatword").